# Insert Options Rules with AND taking precedence over OR

Tags: rules-engine

I have a condition that is essentially `A and (B or C or D or...)`. So for the rule to fire condition `A` **has** to *always* be met. And on top of that, one condition of either `B` or `C` or `D` etc.

I can't seem to get this into the rule though, `or` takes precedence over `and` (as it does in programming) and there's nothing I can do about it?

I've tried to manually edit the XML to no avail.

Comment: The site requires tags, but I don't have reputation yet to add a `insert-options` tag yet and my understanding is that the rules-engine actually isn't what's being used for the insert options rules?

Comment: Your question is tagged correctly, since your question is more specific to how the rules engine works and how to manipulate it, rather than what you are using the rules engine for to manipulate insert options in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. `OR` takes precedence. You can try `(A and B) or (A and C) or (A and D)` rule:

[image]

`where true` would be your `A` condition, and template rules would be your `B`, `C` and `D`.

Yeah, I know it's repeating `A` condition for every `OR` part but I don't think there is any better solution unless you create a predefined rule with the whole `B or C or D` part and then you can use `A and BCD` where `BCD` is a

> where [predefined] rule is true

Comment: I'm gonna look into the predefined rule. My `A` rule is a regex that might need small adjustments in the future so I'd prefer not having it duplicated 4 times. The `BCD` is gonna expand in the future to be around 12 conditions, meaning the regex would be duplicated 12x...